# sum MADlib UDF Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I'm a little lost on how to do this. I am implementing the sum function MADlib. This function takes an arbitrary number of arrays and adds :

```
sum ( array [ 1,2] , array [2,3 ] , array [4,5 ] )
Return : [7,10]
```

I want to create a function from the next statement return the same result, but not how to implement something like this:

```
 def sum[T](args: WrappedArray[T]*)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
     var i : Int = 0;
     for( arg <- args ){
         // Code
         i = i + 1;
     }
  }

 sqlContext.udf.register("sum", sum(_:WrappedArray[Int]*))
 sqlContext.sql("SELECT sum(collect_list(a),collect_list(b),collect_list(c)) from df").show
```

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sum[T](args: WrappedArray[T]*)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
  args.transpose.map(_.sum)
}

sum(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 3), Array(4, 5)) // ArrayBuffer(7, 10)
```

Comment: But as a record in Spark SQL function to several arguments ? Because the statement fails me `sqlContext.udf.register("sum", sum(_:WrappedArray[Int]*))`

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. I thought you just needed the `// code` part to achieve the logic that you described. Function I provided takes an arbitrary number of `WrappedArray[T]` arguments and sums them as you described (note that they need to be of equal length).

Comment: Sorry if I have not explained well . Its function serves me , but as I can not register it in SparkSQL to call from sql

Comment: Your question is not really clear. You will get much more help on SO if your question is direct and "straight to the point". You asked for a piece of code denoted with the code comment and you were provided with the solution which has the signature, return type and behavior just as you wanted it. But now you still don't feel that the question was answered and instead ask something about registering in SparkSQL, which I know nothing about. As far as this question is concerned, I hope I helped to resolved it. Perhaps you should ask another one concerning your problem with SparkSQL.